# Enumerating python matrix by cell value

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, enumeration

Given a matrix:

```
m = np.matrix('1 2; 3 4')
```

I would like to enumerate its **cells** (not rows\columns) in descending order of the value in the matrix. So in my example i would like to enumerate: 4,3,2,1 and have the indexes for each.

I could flatten the matrix to 1d array, order the array and use its index to recover to the original matrix index. But it feels wrong.

Is there some built-in ability in python for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`np.ndenumerate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndenumerate.html) to get an iterator of indices and values.

You could convert it to a list:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> m = np.matrix('1 2; 3 4')
>>> list(np.ndenumerate(m))
[((0, 0), 1), ((0, 1), 2), ((1, 0), 3), ((1, 1), 4)]
```

sort by values:

```
>>> sorted([(v, i) for (i,v) in np.ndenumerate(m)], reverse=True)
[(4, (1, 1)), (3, (1, 0)), (2, (0, 1)), (1, (0, 0))]
```

and extract the indices:

```
>>> [i for (_, i) in sorted([(v, i) for (i,v) in np.ndenumerate(m)], reverse=True)]
[(1, 1), (1, 0), (0, 1), (0, 0)]
```

I don't know if it's possible to do it in less steps. Here's an example with another matrix:

```
>>> m = np.matrix('1 4; 3 2')
>>> [i for (_, i) in sorted([(v, i) for (i,v) in np.ndenumerate(m)], reverse=True)]
[(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 0)]
```

It might seem messy to mix numpy and vanilla list comprehensions. The problem is that `ndenumerate` returns an iterator. You could use:

```
np.fromiter(np.ndenumerate(m), np.dtype('2i, 1i'))
```

but it's a 1-D array of tuples, which doesn't makes indexing or sorting easier.